# How to take image input from user in eel python?

Tags: javascript, python, html, eel

I am using eel library to create GUI. I can't get the path using `<input type="file">` tag because of security reasons. So please tell me a way to get the image and display it in eel interface. I show several questions related to this but I didn't find any full answer.

```
<body>
    <button type="button" onclick="getPathToFile()">Select File</button>
    <img id="myImg" src="" width="107" height="98">
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

#### solution:

You have to use tkinter's file dialog to get files

#### Explanation:

Browsers include a lot of security measures to protect user's data.
Since you are on a local server (**eel**) there are some things you may have to do with python like getting files on the system.

#### example:

```py
# ==> PYTHON

from tkinter import filedialog, Tk, messagebox
import os

@eel.expose
def getFile ():
    root = Tk()
    root.withdraw()
    root.wm_attributes('-topmost', 1) # without that it wil go behind all others apps
    file = filedialog.askopenfilename(parent=root,
     initialdir=os.getcwd(),
     title = "Ouvrez un fichier pickle",
     filetypes = (
       ("images","*.png"),
       ("all files","*.*")
     )
    )
    return file
```

**to call it:**

```js
// ==> JAVASCRIPT

async function example(){
    let file = await eel.getFile()()
}
```

#### Go further:

1. For more info: [filedialog docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dialog.html#module-tkinter.filedialog)
2. How an app made with eel (**auto-py-to-exe**) did it: [GitHub](https://github.com/brentvollebregt/auto-py-to-exe/blob/master/auto_py_to_exe/dialogs.py)